# I want it to show like a sure to continue when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this work, I want it to show me "sure to proceed?" When I click the button to which the ".collect" class is attached.

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".collect");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Sure to proceed?");
});
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="collect">PROCESS</button>
```

Executing the JavaScript after the target element solves the problem, refer to the post anchored to @David 's comment. Thanks.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons this isn't working. Can you please edit the question to include the relevant HTML

Comment: Ok I'll do that

Comment: [Works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/2o7r3nv9/)  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  *As a guess*, perhaps this code is executing before the target element exists?  Or perhaps there's more than one target element?

Comment: I have just one tag with the collect class, and just one button tag in the whole page

Comment: @MrPain it seems you want a `confirm` box not an alert ?

Comment: I run the code on chrome and it doesn't work.

Comment: @ths would confirm work in place of alert there?

Comment: @MrPain: Your code demonstrably works here in the question.  So far my best guess is that you're [executing the JavaScript before the target element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/328193).  But that's only a guess, since the problem isn't observable here.

Comment: @MrPain that depends on your requirements. Do you want the user to confirm before moving away and cancel the action if the user cancels ?

Comment: @David you were right, I put the script after the target and it worked. Thanks all.

Comment: @ths like confirm whether to go to the next page or stay in the same page,

Comment: But it does what I want it to now tho, thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), use [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm).

I created a wrapper called `navigate` that executes the `callback`, if the user hits the "OK" button.

The `performNavigation` event handler calls this wrapper function.

```js
const navigate = (message, callback) => {
  if (confirm(message) && callback) {
    callback();
  }
}

const performNavigation = () =>
  navigate("Are you sure you want to proceed?", () => {
    console.log('Proceeding...');
  });

const button = document.querySelector('.collect');

button.addEventListener('click', performNavigation);
```

```html
<button class="collect">Proceed</button>
```

Comment: Performs well too.